# Как сделать всплывающее подменю фиксированным по местоположению?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как сделать так, чтобы всплывающий блок 980х340px при наведении выводился фиксировано в определенном месте, а не под каждым словом со сдвигом?

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.menu > li').hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown('slow');
                },
                function() {
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                    $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
                }
            );
        });
```

```css
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;   
}
 
.menu {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:50px;
}
 
.menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
 
.menu > li > ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;  
}
 
.menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;  
 background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200);
 width: 980px;
 height: 340px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Раздел1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Подаздел1</li></a>
                <li><a href="#">Подаздел2</li></a>
                <li><a href="#">Подаздел3</li></a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Раздел2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Подаздел1</li></a>
                <li><a href="#">Подаздел2</li></a>
                <li><a href="#">Подаздел3</li></a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Раздел3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Подаздел1</li></a>
                <li><a href="#">Подаздел2</li></a>
                <li><a href="#">Подаздел3</li></a>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> при наведении выводился фиксировано в определенном месте, а не под
>   каждым словом

Например:

```js
$('.menu > li').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown('slow');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
  }
);
```

```css
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;   
}
 
.menu {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:50px;
}
 
.menu > li {
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
 
.menu > li > ul {
    position:fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
   max-width: 980px;
    width: 100%;
   /*height: 340px;*/
    display:none;  
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Раздел1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Подаздел1</li></a>
      <li><a href="#">Подаздел2</li></a>
      <li><a href="#">Подаздел3</li></a>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Раздел2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Подаздел1</li></a>
      <li><a href="#">Подаздел2</li></a>
      <li><a href="#">Подаздел3</li></a>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Раздел3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Подаздел1</li></a>
      <li><a href="#">Подаздел2</li></a>
      <li><a href="#">Подаздел3</li></a>
     </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Думаю так будет лучше, js это уже слишком**

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}


/*| Navigation |*/

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
  display: inline-table;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  color: #222;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav role='navigation'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Our team</a></li>
        <li><a href="">History</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант на CSS, но к сожалению это не решает моей проблемы, блок не выводится в фиксированном месте, если поможете с этим буду вам крайне признателен!

Comment: Может так https://codepen.io/madshaakansson/pen/xwmzK